# Read Querystring parameter inside bootstrap modal popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have below jquery code that load an external page in bootstrap modal popup. I need to pass querystring parameter "type" but for some reason the modal popup doesn't reads it on load. How do i achieve it?

```
 // load modal popup

    function loadPopup(type)
    {
        BootstrapDialog.show({
            title: 'Candidates',
            size: BootstrapDialog.SIZE_WIDE,
            closable: false,
            message: function(dialog) {
                var $message = $('<div></div>');
                var pageToLoad = dialog.getData('pageToLoad');
                $message.load(pageToLoad);

                return $message;
            },
            buttons: [{
                label: 'Close',
                action: function(dialogItself){
                    dialogItself.close();
                }
            }],
            data: {
                'pageToLoad': 'Candidates.aspx?type=' + type
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be sure your "type" don't break the url, you could encode it:

```
        data: {
            'pageToLoad': 'Candidates.aspx?type=' + encodeURIComponent(type)
        }
```

Comment: Its not the encoding issue